# How to speed up query with multiple INNER JOINs

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, sqlite

I've been toying around with switching from ms-access files to SQLite files for my simple database needs; for the usual reasons: smaller file size, less overhead, open source, etc.

One thing that is preventing me from making the switch is what seems to be a lack of speed in SQLite.  For simple SELECT queries, SQLite seems to perform as well as, or better than MS-Access.  The problem occurs with a fairly complex SELECT query with multiple INNER JOIN statements:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       DESCRIPTIONS.[oCode] AS OptionCode, 
       DESCRIPTIONS.[descShort] AS OptionDescription 
FROM DESCRIPTIONS 
INNER JOIN tbl_D_E ON DESCRIPTIONS.[oCode] = tbl_D_E.[D] 
INNER JOIN tbl_D_F ON DESCRIPTIONS.[oCode] = tbl_D_F.[D] 
INNER JOIN tbl_D_H ON DESCRIPTIONS.[oCode] = tbl_D_H.[D] 
INNER JOIN tbl_D_J ON DESCRIPTIONS.[oCode] = tbl_D_J.[D] 
INNER JOIN tbl_D_T ON DESCRIPTIONS.[oCode] = tbl_D_T.[D] 
INNER JOIN tbl_Y_D ON DESCRIPTIONS.[oCode] = tbl_Y_D.[D] 
WHERE ((tbl_D_E.[E] LIKE '%') 
        AND (tbl_D_H.[oType] ='STANDARD') 
        AND (tbl_D_J.[oType] ='STANDARD') 
        AND (tbl_Y_D.[Y] = '41') 
        AND (tbl_Y_D.[oType] ='STANDARD') 
        AND (DESCRIPTIONS.[oMod]='D'))
```

In MS-Access, this query executes in about 2.5 seconds.  In SQLite, it takes a little over 8 **minutes**. It takes the same amount of time whether I'm running the query from VB code or from the command prompt using sqlite3.exe.

So my questions are the following:

1. Is SQLite just not optimized to handle multiple INNER JOIN statements?
2. Have I done something obviously stupid in my query (because I am new to SQLite) that makes it so slow?

And **before anyone suggests a completely different technology, no I can not switch**.  My choices are MS-Access or SQLite. :)

**UPDATE:**
Assigning an INDEX to each of the columns in the SQLite database reduced the query time from over 8 minutes down to about 6 seconds.  Thanks to [Larry Lustig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180368/larry-lustig) for explaining why the INDEXing was needed.

Comment: @Phill Pafford:  I am not using indices on either the MS-Access or the SQLite data.  I'm trying to compare access to sqlite so I have left the data structure the same in both.

Comment: Not able to post an answer, so trying a comment: MS Access is very aggressive about indexing columns on your behalf, whereas SQLite will require you to explicitly create the indexes you need.  So, it's possible that Access has indexed either [Description] or [D] for you but that those indexes are missing in SQLite.

I don't have experience with that amount of JOIN activity in SQLite.  I used it in one Django project with a relatively small amount of data and did not detect any performance issues.

Comment: Use Indexes. Are there Indexes in Access? If not, I still consider it a fair comparison, and still consider it the same data structure in both. Conversely, of what benefit would it be to compare the two products while crippling one?

Comment: @Larry Lustig:  Thanks for the info.  I will trying adding indices to the SQLite data and see what kind of improvement I get.

Comment: Larry is right that if you implement referential integrity between tables, Jet/ACE creates hidden indexes on the foreign key side of the join. I think he was quite astute in immediately seeing this as the likely cause of the performance difference.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "if you implement referential integrity between tables, Jet/ACE creates hidden indexes on the foreign key side of the join." -- that's not necessarily the case. Using SQL DDL in ANSI-92 Query Mode you can create what the Access Marketing Team call 'fast foreign keys' by using the 'NO INDEX' keywords.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As requested, I'm reposting my previous comment as an actual answer (when I first posted the comment I was not able, for some reason, to post it as an answer):

MS Access is very aggressive about indexing columns on your behalf, whereas SQLite will require you to explicitly create the indexes you need. So, it's possible that Access has indexed either [Description] or [D] for you but that those indexes are missing in SQLite. I don't have experience with that amount of JOIN activity in SQLite. I used it in one Django project with a relatively small amount of data and did not detect any performance issues.

Answer (score 7):

Do you have issues with referencial integrity?  I ask because have the impression you've got unnecessary joins, so I re-wrote your query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       t.[oCode] AS OptionCode, 
       t.[descShort] AS OptionDescription 
  FROM DESCRIPTIONS t
  JOIN tbl_D_H h ON h.[D] = t.[oCode]
                AND h.[oType] = 'STANDARD'
  JOIN tbl_D_J j ON j.[D] = t.[oCode]
                AND j.[oType] = 'STANDARD'
  JOIN tbl_Y_D d ON d.[D] = t.[oCode]
                AND d.[Y] = '41'
                AND d.[oType] ='STANDARD'
 WHERE t.[oMod] = 'D'
```

Comment: @rexem:  Thanks for your cleaned up version of the query.  I went back and looked at my query, and it turns out I left out several of the WHERE statements, so yes, I did need all the JOINs.  I still learned a few useful things from your answer.  THANKS!

Comment: Stewbob - if this is indeed the answer, you should mark it as such so that rexem gets the points.  He put in some good work to deliver this solution!

Comment: @Mark: According to the comments, Larry Lustig provided the answer but hasn't come back to post it as an answer to get credit.

Answer (score 0):

If DESCRIPTIONS and tbl_D_E have multiple row scans then oCode and D should be indexed. Look at example here to see how to index and tell how many row scans there are (http://www.siteconsortium.com/h/p1.php?id=mysql002).

This might fix it though ..

CREATE INDEX ocode_index ON DESCRIPTIONS  (oCode) USING BTREE;
CREATE INDEX d_index ON tbl_D_E (D) USING BTREE;

etc ....

Indexing correctly is one piece of the puzzle that can easily double, triple or more the speed of the query.